# Setting QMenu::indicator:exclusive:checked stylesheet causes undesired behaviour on unchecked items

Tags: qt

I am trying to style a `QMenuBar` and its submenus (`QMenu` objects).

Everything worked fine until when I tried to set a custom checked icon.

I have a submenu that contains two exclusive and checkable `QAction`s. I have added both in a [`QActionGroup`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qactiongroup.html) to make them exclusive (as radio buttons are).

When I apply my style sheet without trying to set a custom checked icon, I obtain the following result:

[image]

Up to now, everything works fine. But I find the default checked icon quite ugly and I want to change it.
For this, I added in the style sheet the following description:

```
QMenu::indicator:exclusive:checked
{
    image: url(:/images/checked.png);
}
```

And when I apply it, I now obtain the following result:

[image]

As you can see, **the unchecked item indicator is sunk in the background *(look at the "System theme" item)***. I tried to remove the borders, set an empty (or not empty) unchecked image (:unchecked pseudo-state), ... Nothing worked.
I don't know if it is a bug in Qt but if someone have an idea about how to get rid of this, I will be very grateful, I'm going almost crazy with this problem.

---

**EDIT:**

I have performed several additional tests and it seems to be a bug. I reported it in the Qt bug tracker. You can find it [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-77344?filter=-6).

I have provided **minimal and complete** example in the bug report attachments, feel free to download it if you want to reproduce the bug.

Answer (score 1):

It is late but can help others in future. I was facing the same problem for non exclusive check boxes here's what I did

```css
QMenu::indicator
{
    width : 14px;
    height : 14px;
    margin : 0px 0px 0px 4px;
    padding : -4px -4px -4px -4px;
}

QMenu::indicator:non-exclusive:unchecked {
    image: url(:/icons/custom/checkbox_unchecked.png);
}

QMenu::indicator:non-exclusive:unchecked:disabled {
    image: url(:/icons/custom/checkbox_unchecked_disabled.png);
}

QMenu::indicator:non-exclusive:checked {
    image: url(:/icons/custom/checkbox_checked.png);
}

QMenu::indicator:non-exclusive:checked:disabled {
    image: url(:/icons/custom/checkbox_checked_disabled.png);
}
```

Here's the result:

[image]

The negative padding made icons to draw correctly.